# Mermaid in tabs

Tags: docusaurus, mermaid

The **arrows** are not displayed in the second tab. Bug?
It works here https://docusaurus.io/tests/pages/diagrams#mermaid-in-tabs

I have:

a) In "tab-a", the arrows are displayed:

> [image: Tab a]

b) But in "tab-b", the arrows are **not** displayed:

> [image: Tab b]

---

Version of docusaurus: 2.2.0
Type files: .md or .mdx

````
import Tabs from '@theme/Tabs';
import TabItem from '@theme/TabItem';

<Tabs>
<TabItem value="tab-a">

The following mermaid diagram is shown:

```mermaid
graph LR
  a ---> c(10)
  b ---> c(10)
```

</TabItem>

<TabItem value="tab-b">

This mermaid diagram is not displayed:

```mermaid
graph LR
  d ---> z(42)
  e ---> z(42)
```

</TabItem>
</Tabs>
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copy/pasted the code from [your docussaurus reference](https://docusaurus.io/tests/pages/diagrams#mermaid-in-tabs), so I can see the problem.

I believe that is a **bug** indeed...

---

This is how I managed to work-around:

````
import Tabs from '@theme/Tabs';
import TabItem from '@theme/TabItem';

# Mermaid in tabs


<!-- [start] add this to avoid the possible bug. Note: the empty line before [```] is necessary -->
```mermaid
flowchart TD

```
<!-- [end] add this to avoid the possible bug -->


<Tabs>
<TabItem value="tab-a">

```mermaid
graph LR
  a ---> c(10)
  b ---> c(10)
```

</TabItem>

<TabItem value="tab-b">

```mermaid
graph LR
  d ---> z(42)
  e ---> z(42)
```

</TabItem>
</Tabs>
````

---

**NOTES**

1. I downloaded the page that worked, from docusaurus;
2. I trimmed all code, until it broke;
3. I tested until I found a way to render the "wanted" result, without any extra "artifacts";
4. Now we have a working code, but it is a workaround one.

Comment: I'm sorry I misled you. I changed these symbols on purpose

Comment: Well, it was too easy too be true! Now I found a workaround. And it should be best that you open an issue in their github, so they can implement a correction.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
Created https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/issues/8357